# RegEx for matching time in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to check time input format with regular expression.

I did this to check this format "H:m" (24 hour format):

```
$date = '23:59';

if(!preg_match('/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/', $date)) {
    form_set_error('Error in time format');
}
```

Now I need also to check this format:

```
"H:m - H:m"
```

when

```
$date = '09:00 - 10:00';
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample input and output please?

Comment: If you want either `H:m - H:m` or `H:m` then `/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(-(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/` for only `H:m` then ``/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])-(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$/``

Comment: @dvo Code edited

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thank you, I had to edit it a little     
/^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])( - (2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/, I needed spaces before and after -

Answer (score 1):

```
(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(\s*-\s*(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))?
```

- `(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])` - your regex from question
- `(\s*-\s*(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))?` - optional "- 00:00"

  - `\s*-\s*` - optional space, dash, optional space (remove * to make not optional)
  - `(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])` - your regex again
  - `?` - makes second part optional. Means 0 or 1 of preceding group. (remove this `?` to make it not optional)

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply remove the start and end chars and check if it matches any time, maybe similar to:

```
$re = '/(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])/m';
$date = '09:00 - 10:00';

preg_match_all($re, $date, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $value) {
    echo $value[0] . " is a match \n";
}
```

#### Output

```
09:00 is a match 
10:00 is a match
```

#### Combining RegEx

If you wish to combine two regular expressions, you can simply use a logical OR and place your expressions in two capturing groups:

```
(expression 1)|(expression 2)
```